# Div takes up top empty space

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline

Here I'm creating a timeline odd div I moved to the right side. I want to next div will not leave the top space the red color div start from the top and so on. Can anyone suggest to me how can I get this output. I want to achieve like this

[image]

```css
.timeline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}

.timeline-entry.right-aligned {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry right-aligned"></article>
  <article class="timeline-entry left-aligned"></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you not allowed to change your HTML structure?

Comment: @m4n0 You mean it is not possible? Is there any alternate way to do it?

Comment: It is possible but why are you confusing yourself by starting the timeline from right when normally it starts from left.

Comment: Do you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/iZyldJ

Comment: @m4n0 Actually I'm using the WordPress plugin here I just want to customize it. If I do like this some other things are mashup.

Comment: Then given me the URL where you are using this.

Comment: @m4n0 https://wordpress.org/plugins/timeline-widget-addon-for-elementor/  this is the plugin im using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230664/discussion-between-husna-and-m4n0).

Comment: See the structure generated by the plugin and structure of yours. Even if I give a solution for the structure posted, it won't work for the WP plugin. You may have to adjust it more. Please edit your question completely.